# React form pass headers to api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, post, jira-rest-api

I want to post a JSON to a external api from a react form. the api needs headers (username:password) to access it. I wanted to see how I would set up a form to take the inputs of a user and pass it as headers to the api then post some json. I am able to do this with cURL but Im relatively new to react and this has been causing me some problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using fetch to make API call you can do something like :

```
function signIn(username, password, body) {
    const options = {
        method: method,
        headers: new Headers({username, password}),
        mode: 'no-cors'
    };

    options.body = JSON.stringify(body);

    fetch(url, options)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

You might wanna read more about the same [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers)

Comment: but could I have a form that pass the input values of  'username' and 'password' to the headers then on submit the post of the json happens? and I will look into the link you sent thanks?

Comment: Edited my answer to make it function and this get called on submit form and can send data to the function.

Comment: I made a new question that I have used the and wanted to know if you could help with the other issues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58978655/reactjs-fetch-post-json-to-api

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch(your_url,a_json_object)
```

Here, json_object has one element called headers, just use your custom header in it. But most noobies forget to add the header in backend. I am showing a correct example:

front end:

```
fetch('fdf.api/getid',{ 
method:'post',
headers:{"a_custom_header":"custom_value"}
})
```

backend:

```
const express = require('express') 
const app = express()

app.use(function(req,res,next){ 
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, 
       PUT,PATCH, DELETE');

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type,a_custom_header'); //notice here carefully

  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
 })
```

Comment: sorry,i don't know how to decorate the answer like a code snippet